# How to enable state for one column in a table (React Js)

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I'm using Material UI to create a table in react. The data is displayed and sorted correctly when I click on each column header in the table. However I want the  active attribute to become active only for that specific column when I click on it. The way its working now is all of the column headers just alternate between active and not active (true/false). Anyone have any idea to to prevent every other column becoming active when I just click on specific one? Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableSortLabel from '@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import axios from "axios";

const NumberFormat = require('react-number-format');


const styles = theme => ({
    main: {
        width: 'auto',
        display: 'block', 
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        [theme.breakpoints.up(500 + theme.spacing.unit * 3 * 2)]: {
            width: 1000,
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginRight: 'auto',
        },
    },
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 16,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 2}px ${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px ${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px`,
    },
    table: {
        minWidth: 950,
    },
    tableWrapper: {
        overflowX: 'auto',
    },

});

const headRows = [
    { id: 'market_cap_rank', numeric: true, disablePadding: true, label: '#' },
    { id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: 'Name' },
    { id: 'current_price', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Price' },
    { id: 'price_change_percentage_24h', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Change (24h)' },
    { id: 'market_cap', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Market Cap' },
    { id: 'high_24h', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: '24H High' },
    { id: 'total_volume', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Volume' },
  ];


class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            direction: 'asc',
            arrow: true,
            active: false
        }

        this.sortByNumericValue = this.sortByNumericValue.bind(this);
        this.sortByStringValue = this.sortByStringValue.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false')
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ data: data })
            })

    }

    sortByNumericValue = (key) => {
        const { data } = this.state;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            data: data.sort((a, b) => (
                this.state.direction[key] === 'asc'
                ? 
                 parseFloat(a[key]) - parseFloat(b[key])
                : parseFloat(b[key]) - parseFloat(a[key])
            )),

            direction: {
                [key]: this.state.direction[key] === 'asc'
                ? 'desc'
                : 'asc'
            },

            arrow : !prevState.arrow,

            active : !prevState.active

        }));
    }

    sortByStringValue = (key) => {
        const { data } = this.state;

        data: data.sort((a, b) => {
            const asc = this.state.direction[key] === 'asc';
            if (a[key] > b[key]) {
                return asc ? -1 : 1;
            } else if (a[key] < b[key]) {
                return asc ? 1 : -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }),

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            data: data,

            direction: {
                [key]: this.state.direction[key] === 'asc'
                ? 'desc'
                : 'asc'
            },

            arrow : !prevState.arrow,

            active : !prevState.active

        }));
   }


    render() {

        const { classes } = this.props;



        return (
            <main className={classes.main}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
                <Table className={classes.table}>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>

                        {headRows.map(row => (
                    <TableCell
                     key={row.id}
                     padding={row.disablePadding ? 'none' : 'default'}
                    >
                    <TableSortLabel
                    active={this.state.active}
                    direction={this.state.arrow ? 'asc' : 'desc'}
                    onClick = {() => row.id === "name" || row.id === "market_cap_rank" ? this.sortByStringValue(row.id) : this.sortByNumericValue(row.id)}
                    >
                    {row.label}
                    </TableSortLabel>
                    </TableCell>
                     ))}

                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {this.state.data.map((n, index) => {
                               return (
                                <TableRow
                                    key={index}
                                >
                                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row" >
                                        {n.market_cap_rank}
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell >{n.name} </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell ><NumberFormat value={n.current_price} displayType={'text'} decimalScale={2} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></TableCell>
                                    <TableCell ><NumberFormat value={n.price_change_percentage_24h} displayType={'text'} decimalScale={2} /><span>%</span></TableCell>
                                    <TableCell ><NumberFormat value={n.market_cap} displayType={'text'} decimalScale={2} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></TableCell>
                                    <TableCell ><NumberFormat value={n.high_24h} displayType={'text'} decimalScale={2} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></TableCell>
                                    <TableCell ><NumberFormat value={n.total_volume} displayType={'text'} decimalScale={2} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            );
                        })}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
                </div>
            </Paper>
            </main>
        );
    }
}


Test.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default (withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Test)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some css when you click on some column that time active css should be there and when you click other one previously should be false and current item shoud be active. Like this you can acheive the functionality.